# DateTime from Javascript post to Controller in ASP.NET results in null (01/01/0001)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime

This is driving me crazy, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848463/controller-parameter-null-when-using-jquery-post-and-asp-net-mvc). If I use a standard form and no javascript the  controller correctly binds the datetime. However when I'm posting from a form it always binds as null:

```
"MyObject.Name": "Test name",
"MyObject.Date": "5/1/2001"
```

I've tried a couple of variations, 5-1-2001, etc. but cannot seem to get it to take. I can confirm that it is being passed to the server as it shows up in the Request.Form string. My culture is Gregorian and I've set:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

In Application_BeginRequest(). What gives?

Comment: Have you looked at the Request itself? Something like firebug should help.  Then look at the POST value for a normal post vs the jquery post? Is the value formatted any differently?

Comment: Checked with fiddler, values are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using leading zeros, like "05/01/2001"?

The invariant culture's standard date formats include "MM/dd/yyyy" but not "M/d/yyyy", so if it works, that's why. Ideally you would use one of the non-culture-specific formats like the 'O' roundtrip pattern. Then it wouldn't matter what culture you were using on the server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip

Comment: I tried with the leading zeroes. Did not work.
I tried "o" roundtrip problem and it did not work.
To make sure I'm not going crazy I created a string field to send it to and it correctly sends it ("2001-05-01T00:00:00.0000000") while the DateTime field remains null ("01/01/0001 00:00:00")

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a localization issue? [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx) blog post describes a common localization pitfall with DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is value type and not reference type and it takes `DateTime.MinValue` if you don't initialize it.
you have to declare it as:

```
DateTime? dt;
```

Or

```
Nullable<DateTime> dt;
```

`DateTime?` is shorthand for `Nullable<DateTime>`